# C language: what does this error mean?

Tags: c

```
TYPE *a = calloc(nelem, sizeof(TYPE));
```

It says "unable to resolve identifier TYPE".  What does this mean?

Here is the code our professor gave us.  We need to implement heapsort (did that in Java, and I know how it works, but I am a C virgin.)

Comment: @earlNameless I think the problem is that it's not defined .. ?

Comment: Hi this code snippet was given to us by our Professor.  I'll add the entire code he gave us because I think that might help.

Comment: @Levon, probably, but it could be that `TYPE` is a define that points to another define that points to another (or a few) define, etc.  So it might not be trivial with the C's `define` chains.

Comment: @CheaIndian, then `TYPE` is just a token and needs to be filled in with an actual type such as `int` or `double`.

Comment: How are you compiling your code? You need to define exactly one of `float` or `double` for `TYPE` in the command line

Comment: I think your professor is trying to some [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) in C, replace TYPE with the data type you want for your Heap but take care that it should be a numeric one

Comment: gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DPRNT -DTYPE=double -D{BUBB} *.c

that is what im using to compile

Comment: Try using `gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DPRNT -DTYPE=double -DBUBB *.c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following define to the begining of the file:

```
#define TYPE int
```

or

```
#define TYPE float
```

Take care that `TYPE` replacement should be a numerical type

Comment: its still saying macro names must be identifiers :(

Comment: @CheaIndian Can you please post the compiler's error message?

Comment: <command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers

Comment: Please move the `#define TYPE int` line and paste it after the `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {` line. Post the compiler error if any

Comment: <command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:17:0: warning: "TYPE" redefined [enabled by default]
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers

Comment: @CheaIndian I splitted the code in the required files, and could compile it using: `gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DPRNT -DTYPE=float -DBUBB  *.c` without problems

Comment: ah yes that works.  however all it says is ld returned 1 exist status.

Comment: @CheaIndian Also added the `#define TYPE float` line after the `#define SRT_H` in the `srt.h` and compile it using: `gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DPRNT -DBUBB *.c` without errors

Comment: also what do you mean by splitted?

Comment: @CheaIndian it means that the linker found an error in the linking process

Comment: in class when the professor executed his code it would say pass or fail

Comment: @CheaIndian I created 5 separated files and placed your code accordingly in every one of those files, the files are: `srt.h srtmerg.c srtinsr.c srtbubb.c main.c`, the code you posted has comments indicating the begining and end of every file

Comment: yeah i have a folder called sort and i made those 5 files as well

Comment: thanks for all ur help h3nr1x.  can you help me with one more thing?  how do i make it say pass or fail as the program did in class?

Comment: @CheaIndian Yeah of course, but the code compiled without any errors? The linker (`ld` program) shouldn't return 1 (error code)

Comment: @CheaIndian what compiler version and operative system did your professor use for compiling?

Comment: here's the output:

C:\Users\owner\Desktop\Sort>gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DPRNT -DTYPE=double -DBUBB *.c
C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\ccE1HKEe.o:test.c:(.text+0x2b): multiple definition of `main'
C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUBKqwE.o:main.c:(.text+0x2b): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @CheaIndian "of course multiple main lol", don't worry, that happens ;), Did it work now?

Comment: yes it is compiling.  how do i make it output so i can see if it passes or fails.

Comment: we are learning C right now.  this is a level 2 cs class so we know java from level 1but we learn python, C and C++ in here.

Comment: well we aren't taught anything just the concepts and theory the programming we're on our own so it can be kind of tough when this is ur second time programming ever lol xD

Comment: @CheaIndian after running your program using `-DBUBB`, `-DINSR` and `-DMERG` (couldn't run `-DHEAP` because it reports that `srtheap.h` doesn't exist at compilation), I only get a lot of numbers as output, being `-DMERG` the fastest among all. Didn't get the "fail" neither the "pass" message

Comment: @CheaIndian Don't worry, the important thing is that you're doing the effort, keep the good work, it'll be rewarded in time. I think that you have (as an assigment) to implement the `srtheap.h` file (correct me if I'm wrong) and run the data comparing with the output of the other files

Comment: @CheaIndian yes, to run the program use `./a.out`, also you can change the compiled program name by using: `gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DPRNT -DTYPE=float -DBUBB *.c -o PROGRAM_NAME`

Comment: yes i learned about heap sort in cs level 1 class, and wrote a function heapsrt in java on which i got a 100.  i am gonna use that as a guide line and make a small outline of this program and how it is working with the variables and stuff and then write out some code on paper and try it out.

Comment: Oiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii it printed out a ton of numbers :D

Comment: @CheaIndian good (I gived you an upvote in the previous comment)

Comment: are you a programmer by profession?  any tips for a new guy who wants to do this someday too and be like you and give tips to other newbs :D

Comment: @CheaIndian Found it, to get "pass" or "fail", compile your program using this: `gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DTYPE=float -DBUBB *.c -o PROGRAM_NAME`, the difference is that the `-DPRNT` is missing, check the conditional compilation in lines near line 45

Comment: @CheaIndian Yes, by profession and more importantly, by passion! There are a lot of tips that I could share, but are rather difficult to transmit here, and there are a lot of better programmers in this site that would be more than glad to do that as well. Thanks for the comment, it's an honor, sure someday would be you that will be giving answers and helping another programmers (hope that includes me)

Answer (score 4):

When compiling using the code below:

```
gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DPRNT -DTYPE={float, double} -D{BUBB, HEAP, INSR, MERG} *.c
```

You have to pick either `float` or `double`:

```
gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DPRNT -DTYPE=float -D{BUBB, HEAP, INSR, MERG} *.c
gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DPRNT -DTYPE=double -D{BUBB, HEAP, INSR, MERG} *.c
```

Similarly for `BUBB`, `HEAP`, `INSR`, `MERG`.

Comment: nvm it is saying:

<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers

Comment: @Chea: be sure to execute the program in the directory containing the five files.

Comment: i did i put the files into a folder named sort on my desktop and i am currently in the sort folter

Answer (score 0):

compiler is not able to resolve TYPE, it must be typedef...you have to include headerfile where it is defined or else define it before use. e.g. typedef int TYPE;